# Help with RSA-2048 crypto ransom virus

Tags: rsa, public-key, ransomware

The RSA-2048 Crypto Ransom Virus has devastated me, I tried the backup method, the previous version, the Shadow Explorer, it deleted all my restore points, Its took out 5 HDs and my USB pen that happened to be plugged in, everything is encrypted, all my kids pictures and videos, spreadsheets, PDF's, Music and more. I need to know if I should pay these bastards? or is it possible to decrypt? I have attached a picture of the DECRYPT_INSTRUCTION.HTML. I also tried TeslaDecoder with no luck. Can someone please help? I also can send you one of my encrypted files.

> [image: Just a picture not a html link]

Comment: In the short term, restore data files (not programs) from backups to a _clean_ computer (do not bring the backups to the infected one). Or hope the perpetrator made a silly mistake, and someone knowledgeable and with a lot of time will find it, and make a workaround available (that [happens for some cryptoransomware](http://yro.slashdot.org/story/15/11/28/1824250/decryptormaxcryptinfinite-ransomware-decrypted-no-need-to-pay-ransom)). In the long term, understand and master any tool you use; that's valid for computers and milling machines alike. Sorry, this is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about recovering from malware, not about cryptography.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I am sorry to hear about your circumstances. Unfortunately, the virus that you caught seems to be CryptoWall 3.0 or at least a variation of it. Therefore I am bringing bad news. As stated [here](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-cryptowall-3-0-virus/#recovery) it is not possible to decrypt or recover the files without paying these [insert swearword].

This is mainly through the nature of the encryption algorithm used, as the key used to decrypt your files is only known to the creators/distributors of the virus.

For the future, make sure to have backups of all your data on a drive that is not connected to your computer and most importantly NEVER click on links or open attachments from E-Mails when you can't 100% verify the senders integrity.